# google cloud function deploy start failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Startign today, I'm unable to deploy cloud functions using  gcloud cli.

Here is my  gloud command to deploy cloud function:

```
gcloud functions deploy chatbot_api_gateway_002_test --runtime python37 --trigger-http --entry-point process --set-env-vars VERIFICATION_TOKEN=sometokenhere,PUBSUB_TOPIC=entrypointfunction001,GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=cs-be-dev,DEST_URL=__undefined_yet__,DEST_URLS_TIMEOUT=2 --memory=2GB --region=asia-northeast1
```

I'm getting an error:

> Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
>
> **ERROR**: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Build has timed out

I used to work  same script  1 hour ago, but now- no one in the team is able to deploy cloud functions and getting the same error.

[image: deployment failed]

In the stackdrive logs i see only this:

```
 {
 insertId: "rr5a8qctoo"  
 logName: "projects/be-dev/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  

operation: {
  id: "operations/c2F0YWNzLWJlLWRldi9hc2lhLW5vcnRoZWFzdDEvY2hhdGJvdF9hcGlfZ2F0ZXdheV8wMDJfdGVzdC9SMGdpR0ZRWk13aw"   
  last: true   
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
 }

protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   

authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "myemail@domain.com"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"   

requestMetadata: {

destinationAttributes: {
   }

requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceName: "projects/be-dev/locations/asia-northeast1/functions/chatbot_api_gateway_002_test"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   

status: {
   code: 3    
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-02-05T09:53:42.771914617Z"  

resource: {

labels: {
   function_name: "chatbot_api_gateway_002_test"    
   project_id: "be-dev"    
   region: "asia-northeast1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-02-05T09:53:42.153Z"  
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it please?

Comment: Not really an Answer so apologies in advance - There seems to be a fair few people having similar problems starting this afternoon (myself included). Therefore, I would imagine that there's an issue on Google's side. I don't think there's much to be done other than "Send Feedback" from the google cloud console. Although I'd love to hear any solutions if anyone finds anything!

Comment: @Besperk - right, and this is  a bit scary- we suspect its a problem on  the google side- but according to google cloud dashboard (https://status.cloud.google.com/summary)- no  outages occur in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reads `message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"` so any of the arguments might be incorrect (the change-log sometimes lists breaking changes). See [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) and compare; for example:

> Allowed values are: 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1024MB, and 2048MB.

Therefore `2GB` might eventually be an `INVALID_ARGUMENT` and `(NAME : --region=REGION)` also is being declared as a positional argument. Try to get more output with `--verbosity=info` or `debug`:

```
gcloud functions deploy \
    chatbot_api_gateway_002_test \
    --region=asia-northeast1 \
    --runtime python37
    --trigger-http \
    --memory=2048MB \
    --verbosity=info
```

`--entry-point` would typically be the directory-name of the function,
eg. `helloworld` for `functions/helloworld/main.py` as the entry point.

Comment: Thanks! we can take two things from this answer: 1) --memory 2) --verbosity arguments as best practice. However that shouldn't fix the issue entirely but can help in understanding the issue.

--memory=MEMORY
Limit on the amount of memory the function can use.
Allowed values are: 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1024MB, and 2048MB. By default, a new function is limited to 256MB of memory. When deploying an update to an existing function, the function will keep its old memory limit unless you specify this flag.
--verbosity=info

Comment: --entry-point should be the function you would want to deploy. in the case of this issue should be "process"

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Build has timed out

I would like you to propose **two different workaround that may resolve your issue with Cloud Functions timing out during deployment.**

This could happen because the `timeout` flag is set low or because the deployment is taking more than the specified in the `timeout` flag, and thus, causing the Cloud Function to fail to deploy.

1. When using the `gcloud functions deploy` you could specify the timeout in seconds using the `--timeout` flag.

   As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--timeout) it will set the function execution time in seconds. It defaults for existing functions, but in your case, it would be 60 seconds by default since you are creating a new one. If you feel like 60 seconds is not enough to deploy your code try increasing the value.

   **Keep in mind that it cannot be more than 540 seconds.**

```
   gcloud functions deploy … --timeout [VALUE_SECONDS]
```

2. Given you are facing this timeout issue during deployment, you could configure the behaviour of a specific aspect of the Cloud SDK that should resolve your issue.

   As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) using the command `gcloud config set` will set the specified property in your active configuration only. In order to increase the total timeout you could use `cloud_buil_timeout` which as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#cloud_build_timeout) waits for the Docker build to fully complete during the deployment.

   To sum up, you could try to run the following command:

```
   gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout VALUE
```

I hope it helps.